# How would an ascent and descent action be described?

Tags: verbs

My brother was watching a TV Show called The Flash this morning and it called my attention when The Flash runs to save a man who was about to fall off the building, he goes up there and brings him down. Check this image out: [image: Flash]

It's hard to spot him due to the bad quality, but in this pic, he is already running to save the man, and that is the building. So, how would this action be described?

*He is running up the building?*

*He is running towards up the building?*

*He is running upwards the building?*

*He is running over the building?*

And also in the descent, after he has grabbed the guy and is on his way down, how would it be described?

*He is running down the building?*

Comment: Can you use "he climbed up, and then down"?

Comment: @NVZ He doesn't climb, he just runs.

Comment: I would say "running up/down the side of the building"

Comment: It's not that unusual for language to not precisely match situations that don't occur in real life.

Comment: Shades of Kate Bush. "running up that building"...

Comment: And because it’s an unusual action for a person to be performing, an intensifier like, “he is running ***right*** up [the side of] the building.” or “he is running ***straight*** up the side of the building.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet of the four you've offered is the first, *He is running up the building.*

The second and third are not grammatically correct (you wouldn't say *towards up* or *upwards the*). The fourth is not accurate because *running over* implies he's moving across the top of the building, which isn't the case. So yes, the first is the winner there.

For purposes of clarity, though, I would use something like:

> *He's running **up the side** of the building*

Or:

> *He's running **up the face** of the building*

That way, there's no mistaking what's actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

*"He is running up the side of the building."*

The verb itself is enough to express the capability of the person performing the seemingly absurdist action.  Referencing the side of a building conveys the actual direction of the runner.

It's very similar to "running up the hill", but with an extreme angle implicit with sides of buildings.